# avoid LinkedIn recipients to see each other’s names and email addresses in connection Message

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, linkedin-api

I am trying to send message to Linked connections,how can send the message to 10 recipients  and avoid the recipient to see the other recipients.
what is the property to add to Body Object??

```
var BODY = {
                            "recipients": {
                                "values": [
                                    {
                                    "person":
                                        {
                                            "_path": "/people/~",
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                    "person":
                                        {
                                            "_path": "/people/RJO-_FYNp-",
                                        }
                                    },                        
                                    {
                                    "person": 
                                        {
                                            "_path": "/people/U-GyYIV2ZU",
                                        }
                                    }
                                    ]
                            },
                            "subject": "Time line Cloud",
                            "body": "Hi All this is a test message im trying to use LinkedIn API and im so sorry if i bother you.\n http://goo.gl/OUvDP"
                        }
            IN.API.Raw("/people/~/mailbox")
           .method("POST")
           .body(JSON.stringify(BODY))
           .result(function error(e) { alert("Done"); })
           .error(function error(e) { alert("Error"); });
```

Comment: What other fields do you have besides "recipient", "subject" and "body". You're looking for something that will do a BCC.

Comment: yes that's what i want. if i send the message to 10 recipient the all other recipient will know to whom i send the message and when linked In send notification to my email i can see the other recipient email which unacceptable to me according to my business.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no BCC setting for the member to member messages via the API at this time. You would need to send multiple messages, each to one person.

Comment: Well crap, that combined with a 5 message a day limit is a real downer